# Python - Construct DF From XML API Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml

I'm receiving the below XML response from an API call and am looking to iterate through the "Results" and store all of the data points as a pandas dataframe.

I was successfully able to grab my data points of interest by chaining .find() methods shown below, but don't know how to loop through all of the Results block within the body given the structure of the XML response.

I am using Python 3.7+ in Jupyter on Windows.

**What I've Tried:**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


soup = BeautifulSoup(soap_response.text, "xml")
# print(soup.prettify())

objectid_field = soup.find('Results').find('ObjectID').text
customerkey_field = soup.find('Results').find('CustomerKey').text
name_field = soup.find('Results').find('Name').text
issendable_field = name_field = soup.find('Results').find('IsSendable').text
sendablesubscribe_field = soup.find('Results').find('SendableSubscriberField').text

# for de in soup:
#     de_name = soup.find('Results').find('Name').text
#     print(de_name)


# test_df = pd.read_xml(soup,
#                       xpath="//Results",
#                       namespaces={""})
```

**Sample XML Data Structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-201-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-201-wss-security-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header
        xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:1234</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:1234</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/dressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-1234">
                <wsu:Created>2021-11-07T13:10:54Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2021-11-07T13:15:54Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg
            xmlns="http://partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>f9876</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="Data">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID>Object1</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>Customer1</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Test1</Name>
                <IsSendable>true</IsSendable>
                <SendableSubscriberField>
                    <Name>_Something1</Name>
                </SendableSubscriberField>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="Data">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID>Object2</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>Customer2</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Name2</Name>
                <IsSendable>true</IsSendable>
                <SendableSubscriberField>
                    <Name>_Something2</Name>
                </SendableSubscriberField>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="Data">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID>Object3</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>AnotherKey</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Something3</Name>
                <IsSendable>false</IsSendable>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're super close, you need to find all of the `Results` tags, then iterate over them, last grabbing the elements you want:

```py
for el in soup.find_all('Results'):
    objectid_field = el.find('ObjectID').text
    customerkey_field = el.find('CustomerKey').text
    name_field = el.find('Name').text
    issendable_field = name_field = el.find('IsSendable').text
    sendablesubscribe_field = el.find('SendableSubscriberField').text
```

However, `SendableSubscriberField` isn't always there, so you might need to check if `sendable` is True first:

```py
for el in soup.find_all('Results'):
    objectid_field = el.find('ObjectID').text
    customerkey_field = el.find('CustomerKey').text
    name_field = el.find('Name').text
    issendable_field = el.find('IsSendable').text

    # skip if not sendable
    if issendable_field == 'false':
        sendablesubscribe_field = None
        continue

    sendablesubscribe_field = el.find('SendableSubscriberField').find('Name').text
```

### Edit: Constructing the dataframe

To build the dataframe from this, I'd collect everything into a `list` of dictionaries:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(...)

data = []

for el in soup.find_all('Results'):
    record = {}

    record['ObjectID'] = el.find('ObjectID').text
    record['CustomerKey'] = el.find('CustomerKey').text
    record['Name'] = el.find('Name').text
    record['IsSendable'] = el.find('IsSendable').text

    # skip if not sendable
    if record['IsSendable'] == 'false':
        record['SendableSubscriberField'] = None
        continue

    record['SendableSubscriberField'] = el.find('SendableSubscriberField').find('Name').text

    data.append(record)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you construct the dataframe inside the loop, or pass the fields of interest back to a list outside of the loop?

Comment: I'd probably just collect the fields into a `list` in the loop, and construct the dataframe from that

Comment: @CarsonWhitley see latest edit as an example

Comment: Thanks @C.Nivs that works! I ended up using list comprehension before seeing your comment. Again, thanks for the help!

df_ = pd.DataFrame(
    [el.find('ObjectID').text, 
     el.find('CustomerKey').text, 
     el.find('Name').text, 
     el.find('IsSendable').text] for el in soup.find_all('Results')
).rename(columns = {0:'Object_ID',1:'Customer_Key',2:'Name',3:'Sendable'})

Comment: how would you approach when the data is nested? Let me know, thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74350398/python-construct-df-from-nested-xml-response

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider use of [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) by acknowledging the default namespace (`http://partnerAPI`). Also, since you need a lower-level value, run `read_xml` twice and `join` the results. Notice all attribute and element values are returned even if missing.

```py
soap_df = (
    pd.read_xml(
        soap_response.text, 
        xpath = ".//rrm:RetrieveResponseMsg/rrm:Results",
        namespaces = {"rrm": "http://partnerAPI"}
    ).join(
        pd.read_xml(
            soap_response.text, 
            xpath = ".//rrm:RetrieveResponseMsg/rrm:Results/rrm:SendableSubscriberField",
            namespaces = {"rrm": "http://partnerAPI"},
            names = ["SendableSubscriberField_Name", ""]
        ),
    )
)
    
print(soap_df)
#    type  PartnerKey ObjectID CustomerKey        Name  IsSendable  SendableSubscriberField SendableSubscriberField_Name
# 0  Data         NaN  Object1   Customer1       Test1        True                      NaN                  _Something1
# 1  Data         NaN  Object2   Customer2       Name2        True                      NaN                  _Something2
# 2  Data         NaN  Object3  AnotherKey  Something3       False                      NaN                          NaN
```

Comment: Would that work for a nested response as well?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74350398/python-construct-df-from-nested-xml-response