# Python - Construct DF From Nested XML Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml

What would be the best way to construct a DF from the below nested XML data?

Each "properties" element has three "property" elements nested containing the "name" and "value" of our data. I tried doing two for loops, pandas read_xml option, and a few other pieces but haven't quite gotten the nested logic figured out. My current approach below is closer, but does not keep the names and values together.

Using Python 3.7+ in Jupyter on windows

**Sample XML Data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <env:Header
        xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:1234</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:1234</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-45333">
                <wsu:Created>2022-11-07T17:02:44Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-11-07T17:07:44Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg
            xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>MoreDataAvailable</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>asdfds455</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME</Name>
                        <Value>asdfdfd12</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME_2</Name>
                        <Value>asdf</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME_3</Name>
                        <Value>fasdsa</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME</Name>
                        <Value>fasd123</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME_2</Name>
                        <Value>asdfd</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME_3</Name>
                        <Value>a0A4f</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME</Name>
                        <Value>0034P00</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME_2</Name>
                        <Value>fasdfs</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FIELD_NAME_3</Name>
                        <Value>a0fasd</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Properties>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**What I've Attempted So Far:**

```
data_output = []
for el in soup_de.find_all('Property'):
    
    dict_ = {el.find('Name').text:el.find('Value').text}

    data_output.append(dict_)
    

print(len(data_output))
# print(data_output)


testing_de_df = pd.DataFrame(data_output)
    
    
display(testing_de_df.info())
display(testing_de_df.head(25))
```

**Desired Output:**

```
details = {'FIELD_NAME': ['asdfdfd12', 'fasd123', '0034P00'],
           'FIELD_NAME_2': ['asdf', 'asdfd', 'fasdfs'],
           'FIELD_NAME_3': ['fasdsa', 'a0A4f', 'a0fasd']}

desired_output = pd.DataFrame(details)

print(desired_output)
```

Comment: Would you mind fixing your formatting? For both the xml and your code?

Comment: @C.Nivs let me know if that's looking better on both fronts, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `<Property>` sits at a shallow part of the XML, simply call `pandas.read_xml` narrowing in on that set of nodes while acknowledging the default namespace (`http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI`):

```py
property_df = pd.read_xml(
    "Input.xml", 
    xpath = ".//rrm:Property",
    namespaces = {"rrm": "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"}
)

print(property_df)
#            Name      Value
# 0    FIELD_NAME  asdfdfd12
# 1  FIELD_NAME_2       asdf
# 2  FIELD_NAME_3     fasdsa
# 3    FIELD_NAME    fasd123
# 4  FIELD_NAME_2      asdfd
# 5  FIELD_NAME_3      a0A4f
# 6    FIELD_NAME    0034P00
# 7  FIELD_NAME_2     fasdfs
# 8  FIELD_NAME_3     a0fasd
```

To delineate by property, consider creating a property group number with `groupby().cumcount()` and reshaping data wide with `pivot_table`:

```py
property_wide_df = (
    property_df
      .assign(property_no = lambda x: x.groupby("Name").cumcount().add(1))
      .pivot_table(index="property_no", columns="Name", values="Value", aggfunc="sum")
)

print(property_wide_df)
# Name        FIELD_NAME FIELD_NAME_2 FIELD_NAME_3
# property_no
# 1            asdfdfd12         asdf       fasdsa
# 2              fasd123        asdfd        a0A4f
# 3              0034P00       fasdfs       a0fasd
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, is it possible to keep the property name / values grouped together? So each properties grouping is it's own row?

I can clean the output df you have, but it's assuming the lengths would be the same and indexes align.

Comment: like the below. I can filter the output df you provided in your answer to each field type and then concat them back together. I don't know if that's the best route and if it would be better to keep the properties grouping together in the initial construction of our df. Appreciate the help.

details = {'FIELD_NAME': ['asdfdfd12', 'fasd123', '0034P00'],
           'FIELD_NAME_2': ['asdf', 'asdfd', 'fasdfs'],
           'FIELD_NAME_3': ['fasdsa', 'a0A4f', 'a0fasd']}

desired_output = pd.DataFrame(details)

Comment: There is no property indicator in XML. Consider `pivot_table` for wide format. See edit.